# File.renameTo() returns true, but file has not been renamed

Tags: android, file, file-rename

I'm trying to create a file for my audio recorder, but this file keeps getting a random name. Because this is hard to work with, I want to rename the file after it has been created with a more meaningful name.

However, even though `renameTo` returns true, the file has not been renamed.

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
outfile = File.createTempFile(amount + "_alarmsave", ".3gp",
                    storageDir);

            System.out.println("Old file: "+outfile.getAbsolutePath());

            File newFile = new File(outfile.getParent(), "alarmsave_" + amount + ".3gp");

            System.out.println("new file: "+newFile.getAbsolutePath());

            if(outfile.renameTo(newFile)){
                System.out.println("Succes! Name changed to: " + outfile.getName());
            }else{
                System.out.println("failed");
            }
```

The LogCat output:

```
01-13 18:27:40.264: I/System.out(22913): Old file: /mnt/sdcard/Personal Alarm/13_alarmsave1623959934.3gp
01-13 18:27:40.264: I/System.out(22913): new file: /mnt/sdcard/Personal Alarm/alarmsave_13.3gp
01-13 18:27:40.284: I/System.out(22913): Succes! Name changed to: 13_alarmsave1623959934.3gp
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

RenameTo renames the actual file, it doesn't change the [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object. If you called `.exists()` you'd find the new file exists and the old one doesn't.

This is because the `File` class represents *abstract paths* rather than actual files on a file system. The idea is that `File.renameTo` gives a new name to a file system entry at the given path; it does not change the path itself.

Comment: That... Hmm. Food for thought.
Weird that the name of the object itself doesn't change. You were right though, the name did change on the filesystem itself. So thanks a lot!

Comment: So, how can I change the name of the actual file. I get the same behavior where I print the new file path, I get the new path, however, the name of the file didn't change ? any ideas ?

Comment: The `renameTo` changes the name of the actual file. It does not change the name of the File object.